# solr DateFormatTransporter

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I've set up and configured this DateFormatTransformer:

```
<field column="data_ini" name="data_inici_dt" dateTimeFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" locale="ca-ES"/>
```

At database `data_ini` is a `varchar` where format data is like `dd-MM-yyy`.

It works well. Nevertheless, in some cases, database contains strings like `1 -12-1982`, or `23- 1-1987`.

Some ideas comes in my head:

1. Try to add more compatible formats to transformer, I don't if it's possible.
2. When, a format is not recognized add a fixed date value...

Is there anyway to treat this issue?

Comment: I would suggest correct the values in the database if you can by trimming it...it would be better...and add a validation in the application side if anyone adds the values with space

Comment: You can use an update chain to clean up your data - you can either add regular expressions that remove whitespace and format your data, or you use a statelessscripttransformer to add custom javascript that does whatever you need with the data as it's being processed.